# How to get free memory on system with vb .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, memory-management, out-of-memory

i'm having some problem with a multithread software wrote on vb .net, i need to get not only the available free memory (got with PerformanceCounter) but also cache and, better, the free memory on the system.
How may i do that?
Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Can you review your question please? I don't know what you asking. Do you mean you want your system specifications? or you want the amount of  memory being used by your software? Can you show some code too?

Comment: Sorry, i mean System free, available and cache memory (on windows) via vb .net code
Thanks a lot

Comment: did you asking about free Ram space?

Comment: yup, free ram, not available...

Answer (score 3):

You can get Free memory from Performance Counter "\Memory\Free & Zero Page List Bytes".

Besides, I uploaded a sample project on https://github.com/stjeong/DotNetSamples/tree/master/WinConsole/MemoryPartOfTaskManagerAndResourceMonitor

With this in place, you can get all of the memory info as follows,

[image: running app view]

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 Public Sub getAvailableRAM()
        Dim CI As New ComputerInfo()
        Dim avl, used As String
        Dim mem As ULong = ULong.Parse(CI.AvailablePhysicalMemory.ToString())
        Dim mem1 As ULong = ULong.Parse(CI.TotalPhysicalMemory.ToString()) - ULong.Parse(CI.AvailablePhysicalMemory.ToString())
        avl = (mem / (1024 * 1024) & " MB").ToString() 'changed + to &
        used = (mem1 / (1024 * 1024) & " MB").ToString() 'changed + to &
    End Sub
```

for using ComputerInfo class you have to import `Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices`

I hope you understood my snippet and **FYI:- The available ram space is dynamically changing one.**

If you face any difficulties on this, Feel free to ask...

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i need the free memory not the available, i always have problem when free almost reach 0, in that case available memory have still many space to use...

Comment: @Alessandro can you please explain what is the difference between free and available space?